# Create exception hook in a thread

Tags: python, exception

The following code works well when I put it in the main module, but the exception hook is not called when the error occurs in a thread, not even if I put the code a second time within the thread.

Any suggestions why?

```
import sys
def myexcepthook(exctype, value, traceback):
    if exctype == KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Handler code goes here"
    else:
        sys.__excepthook__(exctype, value, traceback)

sys.excepthook = myexcepthook
```

The thread is called as follows:

```
t1 = ThreadManager(1, "Thread-1", 1)
t1.start()


class ThreadManager(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        print 9_) # should cause an error that ic caught by the hook
```

Comment: Does the thread run in a separate process? or is it in the same instance of  python.

Comment: It's just a thread, not a separate process: But it's wrapped in a class:
    t1 = ThreadManager(1, "Thread-1", 1)
    t1.start()